# Missing nonzeros in U matrix computed by SuperLU

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

On page 18 of SuperLU's [user guide](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/superlu_ug.pdf), the following sample input matrix `A` is given:

```
19,0,21,21,0
12,21,0,0,0
0,12,16,0,0
0,0,0,5,21
12,12,0,0,18
```

`U` matrix is given as follow in the user guide:

```
19,0,21,21,0
0,21,-13.26,-13.26,0
0,0,23.58,7,58,0
0,0,0,5,21
0,0,0,0,34.2
```

But `dgssv()` produces the following matrix, which is printed via `dPrint_CompCol_Matrix("U", U)`

```
CompCol matrix U:
Stype 0, Dtype 1, Mtype 4
nrow 5, ncol 5, nnz 11
nzval: 21.000000  -13.263158  7.578947  21.000000  
rowind: 0  1  2  0  
colptr: 0  0  0  1  4  4
```

The `U` matrix given in the user guide is correct (you can verify it at [this link](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/)). I wonder why SuperLU produces such a matrix. How can I generate correct `U` matrix from the SuperLU output?

P.S. For ordering columns of `A`, I have used my permutation vector, which is 1,2,3,4,5. In other words, there is no reordering for columns. Rows of `A` are not reordered by SuperLU.

Answer (score 3):

I have found out that the missing nonzeros are stored in `L` matrix. Storage type of `L` is supernodel to speedup the factorization process via utilizing dense blocks. So some nonzeros of `U` matrix is stored in `L` matrix.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp. No problem in answering your own questions, but for the sake of clarity for future visitors of the site, could you please write a more pedagogic answer? Thanks.